# How Embed Gist in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

How to insert dynamic gist code in the middle of posts generated by Wagtail (Django Cms)?

I searched the documentation of wagtail but did not find anything that could help me automatically insert the github codes.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I can't seem to understand whether I need to modify some files to enable gist embed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gist is one of the built in content types supported by Wagtail's [embedded content](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/embeds.html) feature. Within a rich text field, editors can use the 'media' toolbar icon to enter the URL to the Gist page, and it will appear embedded in the rich text content. Within a StreamField, the developer can `EmbedBlock` to the set of available block types, and the editor will then be able to enter the Gist URL into that field.

Comment: I added in the rich text and the sentence appears: Can not find an embed for this URL.
But I looked at the support in github and got the gist in wagtail integration.
What do you think it could be?